# TableView crashing when trying to be loaded by a different class

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, memory, uiviewcontroller

I have this app (contacts style) in which you can add instances to a Table View, and it works fine for adding objects, to the list. The list presents them to a detail view perfectly. I can call the "Add Item" (A UIViewController with a TableView in it) view as many times I want IN my MasterViewController (The UITableViewController, rootControler of the Nav Controller).

When I saw that this worked, and wanted to expand the functionality of my app to let the user Edit their current objects in the list, I added an "Edit" button in the Nav Controller of the detailView, this UiBarButton triggers a method that tries to load that same "Add Item" view that is used to add an Item in the table View. Here's where the weird things start to happen.

If I run the App and tap on an existing object in the list view, I am successfully taken to the detail view. If I then tap the "Edit" button, the "Add Item" view loads nicely with the data of the object it is currently editing. I can then cancel/save/dismiss that "Add Item" view many times as long as I keep calling it from the Detail View. If I then go back to the list view and try to add an item, the app crashes.

If I launch the app, and before anything else, I load the "Add Item" from the main list view, the view will load perfectly, and I can perfectly add objects as many times as I want. If I then go to the detail view and try to edit the object, the app crashes.

**Simple put (If you're too lazy to read above)**: The app crashes whenever I try to load the "Add Item" view from a different controller than the one that loaded it the very first time.

Here's the crash log:

```
    *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], 
    /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:6061
     2012-03-26 21:22:49.087 Vex Try 5[2749:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
    'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
    *** First throw call stack: ...
```

Apparently, the second time it tries to load, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is returning a weird cell.

Here's how I call it in the list view:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
    {
        if (!_objects) {
             _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }

        BIDVexTeam *newTeam = [[BIDVexTeam alloc] init];
        [_objects insertObject:newTeam atIndex:0];

        if (!self.addNew) {
            self.addNew = [[BIDEditViewController alloc] init];
        }

        if (!self.editNavController) {
            self.editNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.addNew];
        }

        addNew.title = @"Add New";
        addNew.team = newTeam;
        addNew.parent = self;

        [self presentModalViewController:self.editNavController animated:YES];

    }
```

And here's how I call it from the Detail View:

```
    - (IBAction)editTeam:(id)sender {

        if (!self.editView) {
            self.editView = [[BIDEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BIDEditViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        }

        if (!self.editNavController) {
            self.editNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.editView];
        }

        editView.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Edit %@", detailTeam.number];
        self.editView.team = self.detailTeam;

        [self presentModalViewController:editNavController animated:YES];
    }
```

**Edit**: Here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath Method... Didn't paste it here because it's quite long, as well as a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve:

http://www.clubpenguinaccess.com/extra/cellforrow-method.rtf

[screenshot http://www.clubpenguinaccess.com/extra/app-screenshot.png](http://www.clubpenguinaccess.com/extra/app-screenshot.png)

Comment: Posted. It was too long, so I uploaded it in a rtf format (so it would keep Xcode's colors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly indicates a potential to crash.  Any of lines that do this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

...may return nil if there's no reusable cell already allocated.  In some cases, you do the allocation, like in this case:

```
} else if (indexPath.row == kImageRow) {

    static NSString *ImageCellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ImageCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ImageCellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
```

.. but not in several others.  A good hypothesis for the crash is that it's running a path where none of those cell allocations are triggered.

Please search for all of the dequeue calls, add a check for a nil return, and allocate an appropriate cell.  I think your crash will be fixed.

Comment: Wow that solved the crash! Thanks, never would've thought of that.. How ever, how do I initialize the cell if I want it to load a nib file? I tried this: `cell = [[BIDStandardCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:StandardCellIdentifier];` inside the if (cell == nil) condition and got this: [link](http://www.clubpenguinaccess.com/extra/emptyfields.png)

Comment: Also tried a simple `cell = [[BIDStandardCell alloc] init]` but got the same results :\ Any tips on this?

Comment: It looks like you are able to load some cells successfully from a nib (like the ImageCell snippet above), can you reuse that approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your default case. You've directly used `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` in some cases which works only if a cell has already been created to prevent repeated memory allocations. You cannot reuse a cell without creating it first. So my guess is that in some cases, your cell is being reused without being created first